# ¿Se puede llamar a un método de una clase sin crear una instancia de esa clase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, clase

Se crean dos clases:

```
class SumaExtrana:
    def sumita(self,num1,num2):
        self.a=num1+num2-3
        print(self.a)

class Numero:
    def __init__(self,b=0):
        self.x=3.1524+b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numero1=Numero(3)
    numero2=Numero(4)
    print(numero1.x,numero2.x)
    #se desea utilizar el método de la clase Suma Extraña sin crear una 
    # instancia de esa clase
    SumaExtrana.sumita(numero1.x,numero2.x)
```

Sin embargo se tiene este error:

> TypeError: sumita() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num2'

Repito ,se desea solo utilizar el método de la clase `SumaExtrana` pero sin tener que crear una instancia de la clase, que no se utilizaría en otra parte del código.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La respuesta ya te la ha dado Héctor, esto es solo para ampliar un poco la información.

Si tienes un método declarado como **método de instancia**, como es tu caso, la respuesta corta es **no**, no sin modificar la clase original. Ese método tiene como primer parámetro `self` lo que indica que espera una instacia de la clase. Si ese método no usara ningún atributo de la instancia/clase dentro de él (cosa rara, ya que la razón de ser de un método es modificar el comportamiento/estado de un objeto) "nada" te impide pasarle cualquier cosa a `self` (excepto porque es una trampa, mala práctica, poco claro, peligroso y queda feo XD):

```
class SumaExtrana:
    def sumita(self,num1,num2):
        a=num1+num2-3
        print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SumaExtrana.sumita(None,5,6)
```

Esto no se debe hacer, pero en tu caso se usa `self.a`, `a` es un atributo de instancia por lo que debe recibir como primer parámetro una instancia válida con el atributo `a` para que pueda funcionar.

Como te comenta Héctor en su respuesta se podría declarar el método como estático mediante el decorador `@staticmethod` pero eso requiere modificar la clase. Además, cambiar el método a un método estático es equivalente (a grandes rasgos) a sacar el método de la clase y ponerlo como una función global del módulo (la diferencia es el namespace principalmente). La razón de ser de `@staticmethod` es generalmente brindar la posibilidad de empaquetar y ordenar el código. Además de permitir ordenar el código, también permite que una instancia de la clase pueda sobreescribir el método, cosa que no sería posible si se declarara fuera de la misma.

Declarar el método como estático no implica solo añadir el decorador, implica que ese método no modifica su comportamiento con el estado de la clase y que **no puede acceder a los atributos de la clase o instancia** más allá de lo que se le pase como argumentos. Es decir, en la clase original no podría usar ni modificar el atributo `a` ya que este pertenece a la instancia o clase (no defines `a` en tu ejemplo):

```
class SumaExtrana:

    @staticmethod
    def sumita(num1,num2):
        a=num1+num2-3
        print(a)
```

La razón de hacer lo que quieres es no crear una instancia de tu clase por cuestiones de eficiencia, el problema es que el método esta definido como un método de instancia y, además, usa atributos propios de la clase o instancia por lo que no hay forma de hacer lo que quieres sin modificar la clase `SumaExtrema`.

Comment: Mucas gracias por tu respuesta y tiempo ahora me quedo todo claro.

Answer (score 4):

Si, debería usar una anotación de método estático, de esta manera puedes acceder al método de la clase sin instanciarla. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def the_static_method(x):
        print x

MyClass.the_static_method(2) # outputs 2
```

Este método no valdría en Python 2.2 o 2.3, pero estás trabajando según tu etiqueta con 3. Así que te valdría

Aquí te dejo un [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python) con más información

Answer (score 0):

Sí es posible
Desde la Clase NO es necesario @staticmethod. Desde el Objeto SÍ es necesario

```
#Ejemplo simple de cuando es necesario @staticmethod
class A:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        pass
    @staticmethod    # Se puede poner y quitar # para ver diferencias
    def hello():
        print ("Hello World")
A.hello()        # Desde la Clase funciona con y también sin @staticmethod
a=A("AA")        #Se crea objeto 
a.hello()        #Desde el objeto sólo funciona con @staticmethod !!!!
#RESUMEN: @staticmetod sólo es necesario si se invoca desde un Objeto de una Clase construida con __init__
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os, sys
#
class archivo:

    def _init_(self):
        self.lista = []
    #SE inisiara un archivo txt
    def Iniciar_Archivo(self):
        archivo = open("agenda.txt","a")
        archivo.close()


    def guardar(self):
        archivo = open("agenda.txt","w")
        self.lista.sort()
        for elemento in self.lista:
            archivo.write(elemento + "\n")
        archivo.close()


    def Cargar_Contactos(self):
        archivo = open("agenda.txt","r")
        linea = archivo.readline()
        if linea :
            while linea:
                """
                Esto es para indicar el ulfima caracter de la linea (-)
                es le fin de la linea  y los (:) es el inisio de la linea
                asta la posicion (-1 ) que viene siendo el salto de linea (\n)
                """
                if linea [-1] =='\n':
                    linea = linea [:-1]
                self.lista.append(linea)
                linea = archivo.readline()
        archivo.close()



    def crear_Contacto(self):
        Nombre = input("Escribe tu nombre: ")
        Apeido = input("Escribe tu apeido:  ")
        Telefono = input("Escribe tu telefono: ")
        self.lista.append(Nombre + "/" + Apeido + "/" + Telefono)


    def Almacenar_Contacto (self):
        self.lista.sort()
        for elemento in self.lista: 
            ceparar = elemento.split('/')
            print("Nombre: " + ceparar[0])
            print("Apeido: " + ceparar[1])
            print("Telefono: " + ceparar[2])
            print("************************")



    def Actualizar_Contactos(self):
        Nombre = input("Inserta el nombre que quieres buscar: ")
        # esto es porqque totabia no encontramos el contacto que queremos
        No_Encontrado = true
        for elemento in self.lista:
            ceparar = elemento.split('/')
            if Nombre in ceparar[0]:
                print("Nombre: " + ceparar[0])
                print("Apeido: " + ceparar[1])
                print("Telefono: " + ceparar[2])
                print("************************")
            # Aqui ya lo encontro por eso se buelbe falso
            No_Encontrado = False 
        #aqui es cuando no esta el contacto en agenda
        if No_Encontrado == True: 
            print("Contacto no encontrado ")


    def eliminar(self):
        Nombre = input("Inserta el contacto  que quieres eliminar:")
        No_Encontrado = true
        for elemento in self.lista:
            ceparar = elemento.split('/')
            if Nombre in ceparar[0]:
                self.lista.remove(elemento)
                No_Encontrado = False
        if No_Encontrado == True:
            print("Contacto no No_Encontrado")



archivo = archivo ()
archivo.Iniciar_Archivo ()
archivo.Cargar_Contactos()
while True:
    os.system('cls')
    print("1.-Escribir Contacto")
    print("2.-Almacenar  Contactos")
    print("3.-Actulizar Contactos")
    print("4.Eliminar Contacto")
    print("5.-Salir")


    #Para poder mas facil manejar el proceso de errores
    try:
        Opcion = int(input("Inserte la opcion a elegir: "))
        # es cuando metes lo que no te pide el programa que agas 
        #cuando metes alguna otra cosa como letras y eso te manda
        # el error o bine tanmbien cunado se pasa de los numeros
        # que estan en le menu marca el error por que en este 
        #momento te estan pidiendo  que eligas una opcion con numeros que son
    except:
        print("opcion no valida")
        imput()
        continue
    if Opcion == 1:
        archivo.crear_Contacto()
    elif Opcion == 2:
        archivo.Almacenar_Contacto()
    elif Opcion == 3:
        archivo.Actualizar_Contactos()
    elif Opcion == 4:
        archivo.eliminar()
    elif Opcion == 5:
        archivo.guardar()
        #finaliza y lo buelve a empezar
        break
    else :
        print("Opcion no Valida")
    input()
```

Comment: Hola, agrega alguna explicación a tu respuesta, las respuestas que tienen solo código son consideradas de baja calidad.